# Getting multiple socket response with every single socket.emit in socket.io

Tags: android, ios, node.js, sockets

Here is my code sample, I am getting multiple socket response to the same user with single socket emit. Sometimes it is also increasing by +1 increment on every server restart.

```
....    
socket.emit('groupmessage', {
                                        username: sender_id,
                                        server_chat_id:chat_id,
                                        user_message:"ownmessage",
                                        server_time:server_time,
                                        message: new_message,
                                        action: "ownmessage",
                                        temp: 'new'
                        });
....
```

Answer (score 1):

> Its because your `socket.on(event, listener)` is executed multiple
>   times (for same event).

Here's something which might be helpful.

**ABOUT:** Response through a socket is received in a **Listener** attached to an **Event**.

```
// Initialize socket
socket = IO.socket(SERVER_URL);

// Turn on event
socket.on(event, listener);
// connect the socket
socket.connect();

// emit data
socket.emit(event, "data");

// disconnect socket
mSocket.disconnect();
// Turn Events Off
socket.off(event, listener);
```

**REASON TO PROBLEM:** When an Event is added multiple instances of same Listener then the action is performed equal number of times.

**CAUSES:** Addition of multiple Listeners may occur as a result of

1. A previous Activity still holding references to a Connected Socket, which is still alive, having same Event.
2. Improper handling of Socket in Activity Callbacks which unfollows the Synchronization between `socket.on(event, listener)` and `socket.off(event, listener)`.

**SOLUTION:**

1. Turn **ON** Listeners on Events and **CONNECT** the socket in **onResume()**.
2. **DISCONNECT** the socket and turn the listeners **OFF** in **onPause()**.